# How can we read multiple properties files from different packages

Tags: java, properties-file

How to write a java program to read multiple properties files present in different packages and merge them as one.
I have config.properties files present in different packages example src/main/resources/folder1, src/main/resources/folder2 ..etc now I want to read those properties files and remove the duplicates and merge them as one.

Comment: Would you provide the code you tried by now?

Answer (score 2):

The [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class extends [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), so it can use all of the `Map` interface's methods, e.g.:

```
Properties p1 = loadProperties("file1.properties");
Properties p2 = loadProperties("file2.properties");

p1.addAll(p2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, it's working for me.

```
 Properties properties = new Properties();

properties.load(new FileInputStream("relative\path\of\config1.properties"));

Properties properties2 = new Properties();
properties2.load(new FileInputStream("relative\path\of\config1.properties"));
.
.
Properties propertiesN = new Properties();
propertiesN.load(new FileInputStream("relative\path\of\configN.properties"));

properties.putAll(properties2);
.
.
properties.putAll(propertiesN);
```

now you have a single property of merging N no of property files.

Comment: Is there any generic way to read properties files instead of adding all the paths one by one,as my root folder will be source/main/resources with in which i have multiple folders

Comment: use  Spring <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:classpath:source/main/resources/config1/*.properties</value>
                alue>classpath:classpath:source/main/resources/config2/*.properties</value>
                alue>classpath:classpath:source/main/resources/config3/*.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property> 
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    </bean>

Answer (score 0):

```
in Spring we have propertyplaceholder you can use it like  <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:classpath:source/main/resources/config1/*.properties</value>
            alue>classpath:classpath:source/main/resources/config2/*.properties</value>
            alue>classpath:classpath:source/main/resources/config3/*.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property> 
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
```